# What is the meaning of the dot (.) in Japanese dictionaries?

Tags: meaning, punctuation

What is the meaning of the dot (.) in Japanese dictionaries?
http://tangorin.com/general/%E8%A1%A8

For example:

[あらわ.]{arawa.}す{su}

Comment: ちょっと duplicate じゃないようですね・・　[デジタル大辞泉や大辞林](https://kotobank.jp/word/珍しい-643832#E3.83.87.E3.82.B8.E3.82.BF.E3.83.AB.E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.B3.89)では**語幹**を (珍しい → めずらし・い)、[tangorin](http://tangorin.com/general/珍しい) では**送り仮名**を (めずら.しい) 示しているようです。ほかにも「著しい」(いちじるし・い vs いちじる.しい)、「大きい」(おおき・い vs おお.きい) などで異なってきますね。

Answer (score 10):

This is the first dictionary I've seen use this particular notation, but it appears to be a delimiter between the part of the word composed by the kanji reading and the [okurigana](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Okurigana).

See how for both of the words on the example page you gave, the dot appears immediately before the okurigana begin.

> 表{あらわ}すー＞あらわ.す
>
> 表{あらわ}れるー＞あらわ.れる

Searching for another word, [焼ける](http://tangorin.com/general/%E7%84%BC%E3%81%91%E3%82%8B), gives me the same results.

> 焼{や}ける -> や.ける